# Extracting GPX / KML routes from embedded Google Map

Tags: google-maps, kml, gpx

I want to extract the route data that is shown below to a GPX or KML file. Being that this map is programmatically created and not a "Google My Maps" type of embedded map, is there a way to download these routes for offline use?

http://gts.groomertrackingsystems.com/map

[image]

Comment: Those paths are encoded polylines returned from the server as JSON.

Comment: @geocodezip Any way to copy/export those?

Comment: There is, but you should check with the website owner to make sure they are OK with you using their data.

Comment: @geocodezip I would imagine so since it is information provided to the public free of use but will send a email and get back in a day or two. In the meantime what options/process would we be looking at for accomplishing this? Would it be exporting "all" data or just what is in the viewpane? I would imagine whatever is in the viewpane is what JSON data will be returned.

Comment: If you look at the code, the POST request includes the bounds of the viewport.

Comment: @geocodezip Got the all clear. Using Chrome DevTools I am looking at the map file as shown below. Could you give me more details on how you would approach this problem?
https://i.postimg.cc/KYqbzt4f/Untitled.png

Comment: I used the debugger in Chrome to capture the responses from the ajax requests to the server.  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/0umdvxr2/3/)